# System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedMemory in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

`System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedMemory` is not available in WinRT. Is that functionality made available somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  See the [DataProtectionProvider class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.dataprotection.dataprotectionprovider.aspx).  Things change a little in Windows 8.  Here's more on [Cryptography API: Next Generation (CNG)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and more specifically on the [CNG:DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/Hh706794%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  See the "Security" section of [this WinRT API list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) for all the specific encryption in WinRT (both CNG which is basically CryptoAPI as well as CNG:DPAPI).